# Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform in [...] when creating an user in Active Directory

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, createuser

I'm developing a Webinterface to manage Active Directory.
Some things I've done are working. For example adding / removing groups to / from a user or unlocking. So I think the connection and authentifikation is correct.

My problem is now, that I can't create an user with the Webinterface. The Warning-Message is:

> Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\create-user.php on line 39
> Fehler beim Erstellen des Benutzers: Server is unwilling to perform
> LDAP-Error:Server is unwilling to perform

For your understanding, I post the complete code:

File: ldap-connect.php

```
<?php
// Configure connection
$config = [
    'ldapServer' => 'ldap://192.168.31.201', 
    'ldapPort' => 389, 
    'username' => 'company\\Administrator', 
    'password' => 'topsecret', 
    'userBaseDN' => 'OU=UserDirectory,DC=company,DC=local', 
    'globalGroupsBaseDN' => 'OU=GlobalGroups,DC=company,DC=local', 
    'localGroupsBaseDN' => 'OU=LocalGroups,DC=company,DC=local', 
    'serverIP' => '192.168.31.201', 
    'departmentShare' => 'Department'
];

function connectToLDAP($config)
{
    // Create connect
    $ldapConnection = ldap_connect($config['ldapServer'], $config['ldapPort']) or die("Verbindung zum LDAP-Server fehlgeschlagen");

    // LDAP-Binding
    ldap_set_option($ldapConnection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option(null, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
    ldap_set_option($ldapConnection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_bind($ldapConnection, $config['username'], $config['password']) or die("Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen");

    return $ldapConnection;
}
?>
```

The form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Create User</title>
        <script>
        function generateCN()
        {
            var firstName = document.getElementById("givenName").value;
            var lastName = document.getElementById("sn").value;
            var cnField = document.getElementById("cn");
            cnField.value = firstName + " " + lastName;
        }

        function replaceSpecialCharacters(str)
        {
            var replacements = {
                "ä": "ae",
                "ö": "oe",
                "ü": "ue",
                "ß": "ss"
            };
            return str.replace(/[äöüß]/gi, function(matched) {
                return replacements[matched];
            });
        }

        function generateUsername()
        {
            var firstName = document.getElementById("givenName").value;
            var lastName = document.getElementById("sn").value;
            var usernameField = document.getElementById("samAccountName");
            var username = (firstName + "." + lastName).toLowerCase();
            // Replace special characters and umlauts
            username = replaceSpecialCharacters(username);
            usernameField.value = username;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Benutzer erstellen</h2>

        <form action="create-user.php" method="post">
            <label for="ou">Organizational Unit (OU):</label>
            <select name="ou" id="ou">
                <?php

                // LDAP-Query, show OUs under userBaseDN
                $userBaseDN = $config['userBaseDN'];
                $ouSearchBaseDN = $userBaseDN;
                $ouSearchFilter = "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)";
                $ouSearchAttributes = ['name'];

                $ouSearchResult = ldap_search($ldapConnection, $ouSearchBaseDN, $ouSearchFilter, $ouSearchAttributes);
                $ouEntries = ldap_get_entries($ldapConnection, $ouSearchResult);

                // Dropdown-Optionen, Show available OUs
                for ($i = 0; $i < $ouEntries['count']; $i++) {
                    $ouName = $ouEntries[$i]['name'][0];
                    if ($ouName !== "UserDirectory") {
                        echo "<option value='$ouName'>$ouName</option>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br><br>

            <label for="cn">Common Name (CN):</label>
            <input type="text" name="cn" id="cn" required>
            <br><br>

            <label for="givenName">Vorname:</label>
            <input type="text" name="givenName" id="givenName" onkeyup="generateCN(); generateUsername();" required>
            <br><br>

            <label for="sn">Nachname:</label>
            <input type="text" name="sn" id="sn" onkeyup="generateCN(); generateUsername();" required>
            <br><br>

            <label for="samAccountName">Benutzername:</label>
            <input type="text" name="samAccountName" id="samAccountName" required>
            <br><br>

            <label for="userPrincipalName">Benutzerprinzipalname:</label>
            <input type="text" name="userPrincipalName" value="@markplay.local" id="userPrincipalName" required readonly>
            <br><br>

            <label for="password">Passwort:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
            <br><br>

            <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Benutzer erstellen">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

File create-user.php:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Check, if all required fields are filled.
    $requiredFields = ['ou', 'cn', 'givenName', 'sn', 'samAccountName', 'userPrincipalName', 'password', 'email'];
    foreach ($requiredFields as $field) {
        if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
            die("Fehlende Angabe für Feld: $field");
        }
    }

    // Connect to LDAP
    require 'ldap-connect.php';
    $ldapConnection = connectToLDAP($config);

    // Prepare data for the new user
    $ou = $_POST['ou'];
    $cn = $_POST['cn'];
    $givenName = $_POST['givenName'];
    $sn = $_POST['sn'];
    $samAccountName = $_POST['samAccountName'];
    $userPrincipalName = $_POST['userPrincipalName'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // Create user in Active Directory
    $ldapUserDN = 'CN=' . $cn . ',' . 'OU=' . $ou . ',' . $config['userBaseDN'];
    $ldapAttributes = [
        'objectClass' => 'user',
        'cn' => $cn,
        'givenName' => $givenName,
        'sn' => $sn,
        'samAccountName' => $samAccountName,
        'userPrincipalName' => $userPrincipalName,
        'unicodePwd' => iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", '"' . $password . '"'),
        'mail' => $email
    ];
    

    if (ldap_add($ldapConnection, $ldapUserDN, $ldapAttributes)) {
        echo "Benutzer wurde erfolgreich erstellt.";
    } else {
        $ldapError = ldap_error($ldapConnection);
        echo "Fehler beim Erstellen des Benutzers: $ldapError<br>";
        echo "LDAP-Error:". ldap_error($ldapConnection);
    }

    // Close LDAP-Connection
    ldap_unbind($ldapConnection);
}
?>
```

I hope there is someone who can explain me, what the problem is and can give me a solution.
I use an testing environment with Windows Server 2019 with all updates include today. The Server is the AD-Server. I also use XAMPP 8.2.4. LDAP extension is active.